# Bash ,, and ^^ case conversion are not matching patterns

Tags: bash, case-conversion

I have been experimenting with the bash internal case conversion and found what I believe are inconsistencies.

I define a variable with the value "aBcDeF" and try converting the first upper case character in the range [A-D] to lower case.  I would expect a result of "abcDeF" but instead, I get:

```
$ lowerFirst=aBcDeF
$ echo ${lowerFirst,[A-D]}
aBcDeF
```

It appears to be matching the lower case "a", seeing that it is lower case already and concluding there is nothing to do.

The [bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) says

```
${parameter,pattern}
```

> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion. Each character in the expanded value of parameter is tested
>   against pattern, and, if it matches the pattern, its case is
>   converted.  The pattern should not attempt to match more than one character.

This lead me to study the section on [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) which seems pretty clear that there should be a match on the first uppercase character.

This got me wondering about the case conversion, generally and things don't work the way the man page seems to indicate.

My script:

```
lowerFirst=aBcDeF
upperFirst=AbCdEf

echo 'lowerFirst=aBcDeF'
echo 'upperFirst=AbCdEf'
echo
echo 'Original Converted    Expected    Conversion'
echo "${lowerFirst}   ${lowerFirst,[A-D]}       abcDeF      "'${lowerFirst,[A-D]}'
echo "${upperFirst}   ${upperFirst,[A-D]}       abCdEf      "'${upperFirst,[A-D]}'

echo "${lowerFirst}   ${lowerFirst,[a-d]}       aBcDeF      "'${lowerFirst,[a-d]}'
echo "${upperFirst}   ${upperFirst,[a-d]}       AbCdEf      "'${upperFirst,[a-d]}'

echo "${lowerFirst}   ${lowerFirst^[A-D]}       aBcDeF      "'${lowerFirst^[A-D]}'
echo "${upperFirst}   ${upperFirst^[A-D]}       AbCdEf      "'${upperFirst^[A-D]}'

echo "${lowerFirst}   ${lowerFirst^[a-d]}       abcDeF      "'${lowerFirst^[a-d]}'
echo "${upperFirst}   ${upperFirst^[a-d]}       abCdEf      "'${upperFirst^[a-d]}'

echo
echo "${lowerFirst}   ${lowerFirst,,[A-D]}       abcdeF      "'${lowerFirst,,[A-D]}'
echo "${upperFirst}   ${upperFirst,,[A-D]}       abcdEf      "'${upperFirst,,[A-D]}'

echo "${lowerFirst}   ${lowerFirst,,[a-d]}       aBcDeF      "'${lowerFirst,,[a-d]}'
echo "${upperFirst}   ${upperFirst,,[a-d]}       AbCdEf      "'${upperFirst,,[a-d]}'

echo "${lowerFirst}   ${lowerFirst^^[A-D]}       aBcDeF      "'${lowerFirst^^[A-D]}'
echo "${upperFirst}   ${upperFirst^^[A-D]}       AbCdEf      "'${upperFirst^^[A-D]}'

echo "${lowerFirst}   ${lowerFirst^^[a-d]}       ABCDeF      "'${lowerFirst^^[a-d]}'
echo "${upperFirst}   ${upperFirst^^[a-d]}       ABCDEf      "'${upperFirst^^[a-d]}'
```

This gives:

```
lowerFirst=aBcDeF
upperFirst=AbCdEf

Original Converted    Expected    Conversion
aBcDeF   aBcDeF       abcDeF      ${lowerFirst,[A-D]}
AbCdEf   abCdEf       abCdEf      ${upperFirst,[A-D]}
aBcDeF   aBcDeF       aBcDeF      ${lowerFirst,[a-d]}
AbCdEf   AbCdEf       AbCdEf      ${upperFirst,[a-d]}
aBcDeF   aBcDeF       aBcDeF      ${lowerFirst^[A-D]}
AbCdEf   AbCdEf       AbCdEf      ${upperFirst^[A-D]}
aBcDeF   ABcDeF       abcDeF      ${lowerFirst^[a-d]}
AbCdEf   AbCdEf       abCdEf      ${upperFirst^[a-d]}

aBcDeF   abcdeF       abcdeF      ${lowerFirst,,[A-D]}
AbCdEf   abcdEf       abcdEf      ${upperFirst,,[A-D]}
aBcDeF   aBcDeF       aBcDeF      ${lowerFirst,,[a-d]}
AbCdEf   AbCdEf       AbCdEf      ${upperFirst,,[a-d]}
aBcDeF   aBcDeF       aBcDeF      ${lowerFirst^^[A-D]}
AbCdEf   AbCdEf       AbCdEf      ${upperFirst^^[A-D]}
aBcDeF   ABCDeF       ABCDeF      ${lowerFirst^^[a-d]}
AbCdEf   ABCDEf       ABCDEf      ${upperFirst^^[a-d]}
```

If I ask for the bash version, I get:

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
```

Am I interpreting this correctly?  If not, what am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash manual states:

> The `^^` and `,,` expansions convert each matched character in the expanded value; the `^` and `,` expansions match and convert **only the first character** in the expanded value.

`,` will convert the first character to lowercase if it matches the pattern. `,,` will convert all matching characters. There is no way to convert only the first matching character.

Comment: I see.  The manual says "only the first character", not "only the first _matching_ character".  All of my long winded examples work consistently with that.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: It's a poorly written paragraph; I don't blame you for being confused. The third sentence, "Each character in the expanded value of parameter is tested against pattern," ought to be stricken in favor of the later sentence I quoted.